# Dataloader stopped working after installing Ant

Tags: data-loader, ant, install

I installed Ant and after this, Dataloader stopped working - when I run Dataloader then this window is popping out: [image: dataloader image]
After this, about there is line "The system cannot find the path specified." which is shown by about 0.05 second. What can be the reason of that? Before installing ANT, Dataloader worked perfectly

Comment: Can you launch it from terminal? Then you will have this error written in console

Comment: It shows "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Installing `ant` might have changed your environment, perhaps by adding a non-Zulu JDK to PATH. Check the referenced answer for running Data Loader. Also, the most recent version of Data Loader is v50, it has improved startup scripts.